sqlplus: command not found on Ubuntu 22.04 arm64
I installed oracle 19.10 client on ubuntu 22.04 arm64 like bellow.
# curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/191000/oracle-instantclient19.10-basic-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm
# curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/191000/oracle-instantclient19.10-sqlplus-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm
# curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/191000/oracle-instantclient19.10-odbc-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm
# curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/191000/oracle-instantclient19.10-tools-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm

# alien --scripts oracle-instantclient19.10-basic-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm
# alien --scripts oracle-instantclient19.10-odbc-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm
# alien --scripts oracle-instantclient19.10-sqlplus-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm
# alien --scripts oracle-instantclient19.10-tools-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm

dpkg -i *.deb

but I can not run sqlplus
# export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/
# export PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

# sqlplus
-bash: /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory

# ls -l /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72384 Apr 16  2021 /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus

# file /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus
/usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=abac9e40cfe83fd8802fb2226289640658b3b024, not stripped

# ldd /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000f8e55a50c000)
        libsqlplus.so => /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/lib/libsqlplus.so (0x0000f8e55a3f0000)
        libclntsh.so.19.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1 (0x0000f8e5576c0000)
        libclntshcore.so.19.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.19.1 (0x0000f8e5573e0000)
        libnnz19.so => /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/lib/libnnz19.so (0x0000f8e556ee0000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000f8e556ec0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000f8e556e20000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000f8e556e00000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000f8e556de0000)
        libaio.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x0000f8e556dc0000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000f8e556d90000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000f8e556d60000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000f8e556bb0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000f8e55a4d3000)

# uname -vp
#20~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May  1 16:38:06 UTC 2024 aarch64

any help would be appreciated

I resolved the issue by doing the following:
# readelf -l /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1]

# ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
ls: cannot access '/lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory

# ln -s /usr/lib /lib64
# ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May  7 05:34 /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -> aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1

# /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64//bin/sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jun 3 12:51:16 2024
Version 19.10.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: ^C

